# Uniqueness of loop spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, loop-spaces, homotopy-theory

Suppose X is a loop space; by this we mean there is some space $Y$ with $\Omega Y \simeq X$.

Under what assumptions is (the homotopy type of) $Y$ unique?

As has been pointed out below, the homotopy type of $Y$ being determined uniquely is far from true in general. But for connected $Y$, are there conditions we can impose that make it so?

Comment: It's never unique.  Given any pointed space $Y$ with $\Omega Y \simeq X$, you can take the disjoint union of $Y$ with another (unpointed) space $W$, and $\Omega (Y \cup W) \simeq X$.  This is keeping the base-point from $Y$. 

Comment: You could of course make it unique by choosing $Y$ to be $BX$ but it's not clear (to me) what you're after. 

Comment: The question is, probably: «if $\Omega X_1$ and $\Omega X_2$ are homotopy equivalent, are $X_1$ and $X_2$ homotopy equivalent?»


Comment: Clearly the answer to that is no.

Comment: Don't have time to leave a full answer, but if the homotopy groups of X are concentrated in a narrow "stable" range (roughly the top nonzero group below about twice the dimension of the bottom nonzero group) then there is a unique homotopy type.  Similarly if Y has very small dimension relative to its connectivity.  One can compare the obstruction theory for `$Map(Y_1, Y_2)$` with that for `$Map(\Omega Y_1, \Omega Y_2)$`, together with a comparison of the cohomology of `$Y_1$` and `$\Omega Y_1$`, to get a fuller statement.

Comment: Yes, of course you would want $Y$ to be connected to avoid trivialities.

Comment: @Tyler: this is interesting - what are references for this sort of thing?

Comment: @Mariano: yes, right. The question is what assumptions are needed to make that true.

Comment: You might also ask a slightly different question: "Given a homotopy equivalence of based loop spaces, how do I tell if it is a loop map?"

Answer (score 25):

As Ryan points out, if Y is allowed to be disconnected, then there is no hope, since the loop-space construction sees only the connected component of the basepoint.  But even if Y is assumed to be connected, it is not unique.  For instance, let G and H be two discrete groups whose underlying sets are bijective, but which are not isomorphic.  Then as (discrete) topological spaces, we have $G\simeq H$, and so both $K(G,1)$ and $K(H,1)$ are spaces Y such that $\Omega Y \simeq G \simeq H$.  But $K(G,1)$ and $K(H,1)$ are not homotopy equivalent unless $G\cong H$ as groups.

What is true, however, is that if we remember the "up-to-coherent-homotopy" multiplication (i.e. "$A_\infty$-structure") on a loop space $\Omega Y$, then the connected space Y is characterized up to homotopy equivalence by $\Omega Y$ and this additional data.  For there is a delooping functor "B" from $A_\infty$-spaces to connected spaces, which preserves homotopy equivalence, and such that $B\Omega Y \simeq Y$.

Comment: So this means in general for $Y$ connected, its homotopy type is not unique. But are there conditions that can be put on $Y$ to make it so?

Answer (score 12):

As others have pointed out, the generic case (whatever that should mean in this case) is that the loop structure on a loop space is not unique. However, things get quite interesting whenever we have a space that actually does have a unique loop structure. I highly recommend looking at:

Dwyer, Miller, Wilkerson: The homotopic uniqueness of $BS^3$, LNM 1298

and

Dwyer, Miller, Wilkerson: Homotopical uniqueness of classifying spaces. Topology 31 (1992), no. 1, 29–45.